# распараллеливание кода с генерацией перестановок в си, openmp

Tags: c, многопоточность, распараллеливание, openmp

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо ускорить работу программы при больших значениях входных данных. Собственно сама задача: необходимо для каждой сгенерированной перестановки считать определённые значения, которые записываются в массив (обозначим его `uniq_arr`). Далее проверятся, есть ли в линейном списке (`Node_t`) узел, содержащий данный массив. Если есть, то игнорируем данный `uniq_arr` и, следовательно, саму перестановку; иначе создаём новый узел с таким значением и записываем в самое начало списка (FIFO). Собственно, вот основной код.

```
    #define SIZE_RING 10

    const int ring[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    typedef struct SpectrNode {
        int spectVector[SIZE_RING];
        struct SpectrNode *next;
    }SpectrNode_t;
    void push (SpectrNode_t **head, int spectr[SIZE_RING])
    {
        SpectrNode_t *newNode;
        int i = 0;
        newNode = (SpectrNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(SpectrNode_t));

        memset(newNode->spectVector, 0, SIZE_RING * sizeof(int));
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE_RING; i++)
            (newNode->spectVector)[i] = spectr[i];
        newNode->next = *head;
        *head = newNode; 
    }
    void find (SpectrNode_t **head, int newSpectr[SIZE_RING])
    {
        SpectrNode_t *cur = *head;
        int res = 0;
        while (cur != NULL) {
            if (CompareIntArrays(cur->spectVector, newSpectr) == 0)
                res = 1; // такой элемент уже есть в списке
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur = *head;
        if (res == 0) {
            // элемент уникален
            push(head, newSpectr);      
        }
    }
void countSpectVector(SpectrNode_t **head, int perm[SIZE_RING])
{
    int intSpectr[SIZE_RING];
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    int diffTmp = 0, betta = 0;

    memset(intSpectr, 0, SIZE_RING * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_RING; i++){
        betta = ring[i];
        diffTmp = perm[( 1 + betta ) % SIZE_RING] - perm[betta];
        if (diffTmp < 0)
            diffTmp += SIZE_RING;
        intSpectr[diffTmp]++;
    }
    find(head, intSpectr);
}

    void generatePerms(int arr[SIZE_RING],  SpectrNode_t **head)
     {
        int c[SIZE_RING];
        int i;

        i = 0;
        memset(c, 0, SIZE_RING * sizeof(int));

        while (i < SIZE_RING) {
            if (c[i] < i) {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    swap(&arr[0], &arr[i]);
                else{
                    swap(&arr[c[i]], &arr[i]);

                }
                countSpectVector(head, arr);
                c[i] += 1;
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
                c[i] = 0;
                i += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        int *perm;
        int i = 0;
        SpectrNode_t *head;

        perm = (int*)malloc(SIZE_RING * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE_RING; i++)
            perm[i] = i;
        head = (SpectrNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(SpectrNode_t));

        if (head == NULL)
            return 1;
        memset(head->spectVector, 0, SIZE_RING * sizeof(int));
        head->next = NULL;

        generatePerms(perm, &head);

        return 0;   
    }
```

Собственно, теперь мои соображения. Я не случайно установил в `define` значение 10, потому что уже на этом значении программа вычисляется довольно долго (генерируется 10! перестановок, и для каждой проводится порядка 10 итераций + проход по списку). Нужно распараллелить генерацию перестановок. Но они генерируются в цикле `while`, поэтому простыми средствами `OpenMP`, к примеру, этого не сделать. Также необходимо сделать место добавление узла в список и вообще работы со списком - критической секцией (скорее всего, просто добавление, но я не уверен). Так же в уме пока что использование `CUDA`, но пока не уверен, как её сюда припаять.

В общем, подскажите, пожалуйста, советом. Может, где код исправить, чтобы быстрее работало или поменять где-то саму концепцию.

**p.s.** для генерации перестановок использовался алгоритм Хипа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тормозит не генерация перестановок, а поиск по списку.

Для начала стоит заменить список на хеш или дерево. Сложность сразу упадёт с O(N!log(N!)) до ~O(N!)(в случае удачного хеша) или ~O(N!loglog(N)) в случае дерева. На практике время  должно сократиться по меньшей мере в 10-20 раз уже для N=8.

---

### Пример реализации хеша.

Пара Замечаний:

- Код As-is. Претензий на оптимальность нет.
- Хеш функции честно одолжены, разница в качестве для таблицы минимальная.
- Хеши написаны для little-ending архитектуры.
- Размеры таблицы вполне можно сделать круглыми, простыми сделал их на первых парах...
- Заодно можно будет избавится от деления по модулю при хешировании.

Код:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <assert.h>

//#define HEAP_PROFILE //turn on collission counting

#define LOG2l(X) ((unsigned) ( 8*sizeof (long) - __builtin_clzl((X)) - 1))
#define COUNT_OF(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

#define SWAP(a, b) do { \
    typeof (a) _a = (a); \
    a = b;\
    b=_a;} while (0)

#define SIZE_RING 10

typedef int16_t permutInt_t;
typedef permutInt_t permut_t[SIZE_RING];

static const permut_t ring = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
//static const permut_t ring = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

static size_t hashPrimes[]={ 61l, 127l, 251l, 509l, 1021l, 2039l, 4093l, 8191l,
    16381l, 32749l, 65521l, 131071l, 262139l, 524287l, 1048573l, 2097143l,
    4194301l, 8388593l, 16777213l, 33554393l, 67108859l, 134217689l }; // primes number for hash size

typedef struct spectrNode_t {
    permut_t spectVector;
    struct spectrNode_t *next;
} spectrNode_t;

typedef struct spectrHash_t {
    size_t sz;
    spectrNode_t **tbl;
    size_t num;
    uint8_t size_cnt;
    uint32_t seed;
#ifdef HEAP_PROFILE
    size_t collisions;
#endif // HEAP_PROFILE
} spectrHash_t;

int spectrHash_rehash (spectrHash_t *hash);

inline uint32_t murmur3_32(const uint8_t* key, size_t len, uint32_t seed) {
    uint32_t h = seed;
    if (len > 3) {
        const uint32_t* key_x4 = (const uint32_t*) key;
        size_t i = len >> 2;
        do {
            uint32_t k = *key_x4++;
            k *= 0xcc9e2d51;
            k = (k << 15) | (k >> 17);
            k *= 0x1b873593;
            h ^= k;
            h = (h << 13) | (h >> 19);
            h = (h * 5) + 0xe6546b64;
        } while (--i);
        key = (const uint8_t*) key_x4;
    }
    if (len & 3) {
        size_t i = len & 3;
        uint32_t k = 0;
        key = &key[i - 1];
        do {
            k <<= 8;
            k |= *key--;
        } while (--i);
        k *= 0xcc9e2d51;
        k = (k << 15) | (k >> 17);
        k *= 0x1b873593;
        h ^= k;
    }
    h ^= len;
    h ^= h >> 16;
    h *= 0x85ebca6b;
    h ^= h >> 13;
    h *= 0xc2b2ae35;
    h ^= h >> 16;
    return h;
}

inline uint32_t hashFNV (const void *arr, size_t sz) { // FNV-1a hash
    uint32_t rv = 0x811c9dc5;
    while(sz--) {
        rv = (rv*16777619) ^ *(uint8_t*)arr++;
    }
    return rv;
}

inline uint32_t spectrHash_hashVal (const void *val, spectrHash_t* hash) {
    return  murmur3_32 (val, sizeof(permutInt_t)*SIZE_RING, hash->seed) % hash->sz;
    //return  hashFNV (val, sizeof(permutInt_t)*SIZE_RING) % hash->sz;
}

int spectrHash_init (spectrHash_t* hash) {
    hash->size_cnt = 0;
    hash->sz = hashPrimes[hash->size_cnt];
    hash->num = 0;
#ifdef HEAP_PROFILE
    hash->collisions = 0;
#endif // HEAP_PROFILE
    hash->seed = hash->sz-2; //< should actually be random
    hash->tbl = malloc ( hash->sz*sizeof(hash->tbl[0]) );

    if (hash->tbl) {
        memset (hash->tbl, 0, hash->sz*sizeof(hash->tbl[0]));
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}


/**
 * Tries to find a node with given value in the table. If the value is not in the table
 * insert it.
 * @returns a pointer to either the found or inserted value.
 */
spectrNode_t *spectrHash_findOrInsert (spectrHash_t *hash, permut_t val) {
    uint32_t valHash = spectrHash_hashVal (val, hash);

    spectrNode_t *node = hash->tbl [valHash], *last;
    if (node) {
        do {
            if (memcmp (val, node->spectVector, sizeof(*val)*SIZE_RING) == 0) {
                // we found the node; return ir
                return node;
            }
            last = node;
            node = node->next;
        } while (node);
        // we haven't found the node; insert to the last node
        last->next = malloc (sizeof(spectrNode_t));
        node = last->next;
#ifdef HEAP_PROFILE
        hash->collisions++;
#endif // HEAP_PROFILE
    } else {
        // hash key is empty; insert directly to the table
        hash->tbl [valHash] = malloc (sizeof(spectrNode_t));
        node = hash->tbl [valHash];
    }
    assert (node);
    memcpy (node->spectVector, val, sizeof(*val)*SIZE_RING);
    node->next = 0;
    if (4*++hash->num > 3*hash->sz) {
        spectrHash_rehash (hash);
    }
    return node;
}

int spectrHash_rehash (spectrHash_t *hash) {
    hash->size_cnt++;
    size_t old_sz = hash->sz;

    if (hash->size_cnt < COUNT_OF(hashPrimes)-1) {
        hash->sz = hashPrimes[hash->size_cnt];
    } else {
        hash->sz = old_sz<<1;
    }
    spectrNode_t **new_tbl = malloc (hash->sz*sizeof(new_tbl[0]));
    assert (new_tbl);
    memset (new_tbl, 0, hash->sz*sizeof(new_tbl[0]));
#ifdef HEAP_PROFILE
    hash->collisions = 0;
#endif // HEAP_PROFILE
    hash->seed = hash->sz-2; //< should be random

    for (size_t i=0; i<old_sz; i++) {
        for (spectrNode_t *node = hash->tbl[i], *next; node; node=next) {
            next = node->next;
            node->next = 0;
            uint32_t valHash = spectrHash_hashVal (node->spectVector, hash);

            if (!new_tbl[valHash]) {
                new_tbl[valHash] = node;
            } else {
#ifdef HEAP_PROFILE
                hash->collisions++;
#endif // HEAP_PROFILE
                spectrNode_t *tail;
                for (tail = new_tbl[valHash]; tail->next; tail=tail->next) {}
                tail->next = node;
            }
        }
    }

    free ( hash->tbl );
    hash->tbl = new_tbl;

    return 0;
}


void countSpectVector(spectrHash_t *hash, permut_t perm)
{
    permut_t intSpectr;
    int i = 0;
    permutInt_t diffTmp = 0, betta = 0;

    memset(intSpectr, 0, SIZE_RING * sizeof(intSpectr[0]));

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_RING; i++){
        betta = ring[i];
        diffTmp = perm[( 1 + betta ) % SIZE_RING] - perm[betta];
        if (diffTmp < 0)
            diffTmp += SIZE_RING;
        intSpectr[diffTmp]++;
    }
    spectrHash_findOrInsert(hash, intSpectr);
}

void generatePerms(permut_t arr, spectrHash_t *hash)
 {
     permut_t c;
    int i;

    i = 0;
    memset(c, 0, SIZE_RING * sizeof(c[0]));

    while (i < SIZE_RING) {
        if (c[i] < i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                SWAP(arr[0], arr[i]);
            else{
                SWAP(arr[c[i]], arr[i]);
            }
            countSpectVector(hash, arr);
            c[i] += 1;
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
            c[i] = 0;
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    permut_t perm;
    spectrHash_t hash;

    spectrHash_init (&hash);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE_RING; i++)
        perm[i] = i;

    generatePerms(perm, &hash);

#ifdef HEAP_PROFILE
    int collisionCounters[36];
    memset (collisionCounters, 0, sizeof(collisionCounters));

    for (size_t i=0; i<hash.sz; i++) {
        if(hash.tbl[i]) {
            size_t col = 0;
            for (spectrNode_t *head = hash.tbl[i]; head->next; head=head->next) {
                col++;
            }
            if(col) {
                switch(col) {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                        collisionCounters[col-1]++;
                        break;
                    default:
                        collisionCounters[LOG2l(col)+2]++;
                        // smart-ass for sort array to the buckets there each bucket contains element <2^N
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("size = %zd, num =  %zd collision = %zd\n",
            hash.sz, hash.num, hash.collisions);
    long i;
    bool is_print_started = false;
    for(i=COUNT_OF (collisionCounters)-1; i > 4; i--) {
        if (is_print_started || collisionCounters[i]) {
            printf ("%4d collisions with depth <%lu\n", collisionCounters[i], 1l<<(i-2));
            is_print_started = 1;
        }
    }
    for(; i>=0; i--) {
        if (is_print_started || collisionCounters[i]) {
            printf ("%4d collisions with depth %ld\n", collisionCounters[i], i+1);
            is_print_started = 1;
        }
    }
#endif // HEAP_PROFILE

    return 0;
}

extern inline uint32_t hashFNV (const void *arr, size_t sz);
extern inline uint32_t murmur3_32(const uint8_t* key, size_t len, uint32_t seed);
extern inline uint32_t spectrHash_hashVal (const void *val, spectrHash_t* hash);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий! Сейчас попробую реализовать в виде двоичного дерева.

Comment: Только двоичное дерево реализованное в лоб тоже может быть не лучшим вариантом: надо минимизировать количество сравнений массива... лучше всего должен подойти хеш (не знаю, почему я написал «куча» в ответе [fixed]).

Comment: не могли бы Вы пояснить примером?

Comment: я имею в виду, что, как минимум, при обходе дерева я бы массив сравнивал не с первого элемента, а с того за которым предыдущие два сравнения показали равенство, хотя это может быть и преждевременно... я не особо вникал, на сколько данные получаются разбросаны.

Comment: К сожалению, математической взаимосвязи между элементами дерева не выявлено :(

Comment: Набросал хеш... для N=10 — 0.17секунд (в прошлый раз терпения у меня не хватило дождаться); для N=11—2.01с, для 12 —27.80с, для 13 —446.44с... в общем укладывается в ожидаемое O(n!)+ замедление за счёт большого количества кеш-промахов для большой таблицы... Дальше факториальная сложность бьёт сильнее и больнее... если заняться оптимизировать, то, думаю скорость можно будет ещё на ~25—100% увеличить без распараллеливаиня...

Comment: буду Вам очень признателен, если Вы выложите свой код в ответ или мне на почту.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Какой хоть алгоритм хеширования использовали?

Comment: murmur3 и FNV-1a... разница в качестве практически отсутствует. скорость не замерял. Да, код для Little-ending архитектуры если что...

Comment: такой вопрос возник. Я хочу узнать, сколько в итоге у меня элементов в списке. Куда правильнее всего добавлять счётчик в функции `spectrHash_hashVal `? Я спрашиваю, чтобы быть уверенным, что точно НЕ ошибся при запуске :) Мне кажется, что после коммента `// hash key is empty; insert directly to the table`, но я не уверен.

Comment: он и так есть: hash->num

Comment: О, точно, спасибо!